# Convert And-Or Gate to only NAND Gates

Tags: logic-gates

I have to create a two level circuit NAND only gates for the Fibonacci from 1-8. After creating a truth table and K-Maps, I got the Function F=A'B + B'C. Then I drew the AND-OR circuit and tried to convert it NAND only circuit. After implementing it on our bread board, I did not get the correct output, so I am guessing something is wrong with my circuit diagram. I am not sure. For the truth table that we were given, the directions given were:

Each row in the truth table is identified by a decimal number.
For each row that corresponds to a Fibonacci number, specify the output to be 1. 
Otherwise, specify the output to be 0.

[image: Truth table]

[image: K-Map]

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: Do you understand what the Fibonacci sequence is.....

Comment: In States 4 to 7, A should be 1.  Which makes your truth table so wrong.  But you have a correct term \$\bar B C\$, even though K-map is wrong.

Comment: The truth table is the one we received, we had to fill in the Fib.Num column. So when the minterm number is within the Fibonacci sequence, then we put a 1 in that column, else put a 0. The original truth table was from 0-15 so the last 8 rows were all 1s, but for this one, it has to be from 0-7. We just cut the table in half

Comment: A,B,C are the outputs of the binary bit counter IC we have which goes into the input of our NAND and NOR gates

Comment: When you cut the truth table in half, you took the wrong half...because your truth table can't be true.

Comment: I know the truth table is wrong, but the direction said just fill the Fib.Num column

Comment: Well fix the truth table then. Otherwise the question is nonsensical. If you use the code button you can create a table in fixed width font. The table should have all the binary ABC values from 000 to 111.

Comment: On two occasions I have been asked, — "Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?" -Charles Babbage

Comment: convert or to nand:
a+b=(a'.b')'

Comment: Whether or not zero is a Fibonacci number depends on definition. The *truth table*, given or not, is broken, starting with A invariant. - *What is your answerable EE question*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the De Morgan theorems to convert any OR logic to AND and vice-versa:

!(A * B) = !A + !B

and

!(A + B) =  !A * !B